# Not getting API data length in Tab Controller: Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am getting _videoList.length in my function but not getting in Tab Controller

Here I am getting all video list

```
_getAllVideos() async {
    var categories = await _videoService.getVideos();
    var _list = json.decode(categories.body);
    List<Video> results = [];
    _list['data'].forEach((data) {
      var model = Video();
      model.id = data["id"];
      model.videoUrl = data["videourl"];
      model.likes = data["likes"];
      model.profileImg = data["profileImg"];
      results.add(model);
    });
      if(mounted){
        setState(() {
          _videoList = results;
          isLoading = false;
        });
      }
  }
```

This is my widget in which I want to get videoList length.

```
Widget getBody() {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return RotatedBox(
      quarterTurns: 1,
      child: TabBarView(
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
       controller: _tabController,
        children: List.generate(_videoList.length, (index) {
            return VideoPlayerItem(
              videoUrl: _videoList[index].videoUrl!.toString(),
              profileImg: _videoList[index].albumImg!,
              likes: _videoList[index].likes.toString(),
            );
          },),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Please help me to solve so that I can get _videoList.length in Tab Controller

```
 late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getAllVideos();
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: _videoList.length, vsync: this);
print(_videoList.length);   **//getting 0**
  }
```

I have defined my videoList

List _videoList = [];

Comment: how you define `_videoList` ?

Comment: add more details for _getAllVideos();

Comment: @RohitChaurasiya I have edited and added more details

Comment: @JohnJoe I have edited please check.